# "За очи горда, а в очи раба." Какое значение поговорки?

Tags: значение-слов, значение

"За очи горда..." — перед кем и в каком значении "горда"?

Answer (score 2):

Слово горда здесь в значении "смела, высокомерна, дерзка". Раба - послушна, скромна. За глаза дерзит, а в глаза льстит.

*За очи горда, а в очи раба* - пословица из серии "О лицемерии":

*В глаза выхваляют, а за очи ругают.*

*В глаза ласкает, а за глаза лает.*

*В глаза льстит, а за глаза ругает.*

*В глаза не хвали, за глаза не кори.*

*В глаза не хвали, за глаза не хули.*